# Временные интервалы в дате php

Tags: php, дата

Доброго времени! Столкнулся с такой задачей, есть 2 переменные с датой и временем

```
$progresolddate = '2000-10-10 11:12:00';
$getcycle['time'] = '2000-10-10 12:12:00';
```

дата и время в них может быть произвольная, но вторая дата всегда больше первой (хотя бы на минуту), и надо отследить попадает ли разница во времени в какой-то из временных интервалов.
Я попробовал сделать так:

```
if ((substr($progresolddate, 11,5) >= '00:00' && substr($getcycle['time'], 11,5) <= '00:59') || 
(substr($progresolddate, 11,5) >= '01:00' && substr($getcycle['time'], 11,5) <= '01:59') ||
(substr($progresolddate, 11,5) >= '02:00' && substr($getcycle['time'], 11,5) <= '02:59') ||
(substr($progresolddate, 11,5) >= '03:00' && substr($getcycle['time'], 11,5) <= '03:59') ||
(substr($progresolddate, 11,5) >= '04:00' && substr($getcycle['time'], 11,5) <= '04:59') ||
(substr($progresolddate, 11,5) >= '05:00' && substr($getcycle['time'], 11,5) <= '05:59') ||
(substr($progresolddate, 11,5) >= '06:00' && substr($getcycle['time'], 11,5) <= '06:59') ||
(substr($progresolddate, 11,5) >= '07:00' && substr($getcycle['time'], 11,5) <= '07:59') ||
(substr($progresolddate, 11,5) >= '08:00' && substr($getcycle['time'], 11,5) <= '08:59') ||
(substr($progresolddate, 11,5) >= '09:00' && substr($getcycle['time'], 11,5) <= '09:59') ||
(substr($progresolddate, 11,5) >= '10:00' && substr($getcycle['time'], 11,5) <= '10:59') ||
(substr($progresolddate, 11,5) >= '11:00' && substr($getcycle['time'], 11,5) <= '11:59') ||
(substr($progresolddate, 11,5) >= '12:00' && substr($getcycle['time'], 11,5) <= '12:59') ||
(substr($progresolddate, 11,5) >= '13:00' && substr($getcycle['time'], 11,5) <= '13:59') ||
(substr($progresolddate, 11,5) >= '14:00' && substr($getcycle['time'], 11,5) <= '14:59') ||
(substr($progresolddate, 11,5) >= '15:00' && substr($getcycle['time'], 11,5) <= '15:59') ||
(substr($progresolddate, 11,5) >= '16:00' && substr($getcycle['time'], 11,5) <= '16:59') ||
(substr($progresolddate, 11,5) >= '17:00' && substr($getcycle['time'], 11,5) <= '17:59') ||
(substr($progresolddate, 11,5) >= '18:00' && substr($getcycle['time'], 11,5) <= '18:59') ||
(substr($progresolddate, 11,5) >= '19:00' && substr($getcycle['time'], 11,5) <= '19:59') ||
(substr($progresolddate, 11,5) >= '20:00' && substr($getcycle['time'], 11,5) <= '20:59') ||
(substr($progresolddate, 11,5) >= '21:00' && substr($getcycle['time'], 11,5) <= '21:59') ||
(substr($progresolddate, 11,5) >= '22:00' && substr($getcycle['time'], 11,5) <= '22:59') ||
(substr($progresolddate, 11,5) >= '23:00' && substr($getcycle['time'], 11,5) <= '23:59')) {

echo 'sd';
}
```

Но тут несколько проблем - во первых слишком громоздко. Я знаю, что в php есть много функций работы с датой и временем, да и этот скрипт срабатывает нормально только если разница между датами меньше часа.
Есть ли какая нибудь функция или способ сделать это более работоспособно?

Comment: Тяжело понятно, чего Вы добиваетесь. Можно формулировку задачи?
Ну и попробуйте воспользоваться циклами при её решении.

Comment: `какой то из временных интервалов` - имеется в виду в один час?

Comment: @vp_arth ну по идее просто идет проверка - попадает ли в раздницу какой то временной интервал - они тоже могут быть назначены рандомно, но я для примера привел оп часу

Comment: Непонятно, что такое временной интервал. Например, 2ч. это интервал времени от 00 минут до 00 минут через 2ч или просто разница между датами не должна быть более 2ч?

Answer (score 1):

- Для начала нужно создать из строк объекты DateTime.
- Далее, сравниваем необходимые нам форматы этих объектов
  Например, `$a->format('H') === $b->format('H')`

Пример:

```
$a = '2000-10-10 11:12:00';
$b = '2000-10-10 12:12:00';
$c = '2000-10-10 12:36:00';

$a = new \DateTime($a);
$b = new \DateTime($b);
$c = new \DateTime($c);
$ab = $b->format('Y-m-d H') === $a->format('Y-m-d H');
$bc = $c->format('Y-m-d H') === $b->format('Y-m-d H'); // сравниваем без минут

var_dump($ab); // false
var_dump($bc); // true
```